# What type of encryption could be used by this smart bulb?

Tags: encryption

I want to write an app that can control my smart bulb. I've captured the bluetooth dump that the bulb's official app is sending.

I found that the data is encrypted, i sent the same command several times and the output was always different, of course the bulb did the same thing each time.

There are some examples below for reference. First 3 bytes are not important (they just increment), the remaining 17 bytes are my struggle.

080000  e6 12 f2 2c 8e 11 56 f2 4e 68 92 ad 2b 40 bd 0c d5

0a0000  e2 72 9d ec 04 aa 27 1b c6 91 4b c2 a1 a1 1d 58 c5

0c0000  06 ce 72 cf f5 c3 d7 03 e5 10 2f b3 f0 34 03 b8 53

Question 1: What kind of encrypting technique does this:

- one input at sender side => several different outputs
- the reciever calculates one specific result from several different inputs.

Note that the reciever in this case is a smart bulb with a probably not too sophisticated chip.

Question 2: Could it be that the input is encrypted using the actual time? The time is sent in each packet, so maybe that's how the values are always different, but still the other side can figure out the original values using the recieved time?

Answer (score 0):

Typically encryption adds a random element that is sent with the message so each message is different in order to prevent replay attacks, such as you are interested in.

Given that the encrypted message is 20 bytes my guess might be CTR mode. Potential algorithms **might** range from AES to [XTEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XTEA). But knowing the encryption methods will nit help if the bulb company did their cryptography correctly.

[Nota Bene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota_bene): Cryptographic security relies solely on the key being secret, not the method.